# show_post in wp_query of wordpress doesn't work exactly

Tags: wordpress

I tried to use wp_query loop for get lasted 5 post in category page, I used this code bellow but it turn 10 posts:

```
<?php 
    $category = get_queried_object();
    $ids =  $category->term_id;
    $args = array(
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'show_post' => 5, // try to 'posts_per_archive_page' , 'posts_per_page but still show 10 post
        'cat' => $ids,
    );
    ?>
    <?php $getposts = new WP_query($args); ?>
    <?php global $wp_query; $wp_query->in_the_loop = true; ?>
    <?php while ($getposts->have_posts()) : $getposts->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="tax_top_content_wrap">
            <div class="tax_top_left_img">
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt=""></a>
            </div>
            <div class="tax_top_left_content">
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                <p class="excerpt"><?php echo excerpt(30); ?></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Comment: Are you using a theme that is overriding your settings? Try looking for a  `pre_get_posts` hook.

Comment: Also, `show_post` isn't a valid argument to pass.

Comment: Try to use `category` instead of `cat`

Comment: @kaize `cat` is the correct argument name.

Comment: Where are you actually using this code? Is this in an category or archive template?

Comment: I put it to my archive.php , use education-hub-pro theme.